# How to ping, get the ping number, and put it in a label

Tags: c#, ping, dispose

So here is what i do:

```
using (Ping pingSender = new Ping())
{
   replys = pingSender.Send(otherPartyIP.Address).RoundtripTime.ToString();
}
```

So this is being run once a sec, but i wonder, is this really optimal.
Even if ping once a sec should probably be microscopic to performance, improvement is something to strive for.

So, is this better, or will it be the same, or worse (as i think it creates a new all the time without disposing)

```
replys = new Ping().Send(otherPartyIP.Address).RoundtripTime.ToString();
```

Though, when i think of it, it should be better to create a Ping() when i start my application, and dispose of it when i end it.

Comment: What about not constantly creating and disposing `Ping` objects?

Comment: `but i wonder, is this really optimal`, did you perform any metrics on it? You are likely trying to optimize something that doesn't need optimized.

Comment: Matten: That´s what i suggested myself in the last statement, but wanted your suggestions.

The Solution: No, but even stuff like this can be improved, and what can be improved, should be improved;)

Comment: @TheSolution Is micro-optimization really an issue when its blatantly obvious that an `IDisposable` isn't being disposed of? I think it's a good question to ask considering the OP has seen the pattern and is interested in the applications.

Comment: @user2587718, improving something that produces no real benefit, doesn't need improved. However, taking this object **out** of the `using` simply means that you're now responsible for disposing it manually. That risk is **much** higher than the overhead that may exist.

Comment: would suit peer review site better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two examples are identical.. except that `Dispose()` is called when using `using`.. whereas, it isn't in the second example.

Since the `Ping` object is being re-used.. it is definitely a good idea to scope it much wider than you are (in what I assume is some sort of `Timer`). So there is no real case *not* to move it into a wider scope (class level perhaps).

Comment: Where will `Dispose` be called in the second example?

Comment: Well i know, or well. What i don´t know is, what does the other do? Does it create a new object all the time so they will stack and stack?

And, yes, it´s in a Timer, as said, it´s on a 1 sec timer. But from what you say, i guess you mean, i should add it on top like (Private Ping ping = new Ping(); ) ?

Comment: @bash.d It won't. I said it will be called when you wrap it in `using`.

Comment: Then these examples aren't identical, as in the second one, `Dispose` will never be called and memory will leak.

Comment: Perhaps you've misunderstood my phrase.. but I said "they are identical _except_". Maybe I should re-phrase.

Comment: @user2587718 Yes, that is what I am suggesting. Move it into that scope and dispose of it manually when the parent class is disposed.

Comment: Great, don´t know about that parent class though. I dispose when i close the form.

Comment: @user2587718 If the parent class is a form.. then that is fine :)

Comment: @bash.d Thanks for pointing out my badly written phrasing. Appreciated :)

Comment: Yes, everything is in the form class (i am bad at making a structure of classes, so i just have pretty much 1 big class)

Answer (score 1):

If an object has a `Dispose`-method, you always need to `Dispose` of the object, like you did

```
using (Ping pingSender = new Ping())
{
   replys = pingSender.Send(otherPartyIP.Address).RoundtripTime.ToString();
}
```

the `using`-statement makes sure, that all unmanaged resources are bein properly deallocated.

If you use the object during the lifetime of your program, you can also make it a member of your class and create a destructor like

```
~SurroundingClass(){
   if(!ping.IsDisposed){
      ping.Dispose();
   }  
}
```

This will make sure, that `ping` is properly disposed of, when your surrounding object goes out of scope.

Comment: Why wouldn't you advise that the scope of the `Ping` instance be moved into a larger scope.. such as class-level?

Comment: Not sure what to do with that Class, can´t i just add it in, Form.Closing or something, or is that a bad idea?

Comment: Well, if it is a part of your form and the only form you have and will work on, you don't even need to dispose of it, as memory will be released when the process terminates. This is bad practice, though! Always dispose of your unmanaged resources!

Comment: So meaning, i can ignore disposing as closing will dispose. BUT there is no reason NOT to do it, and as this is a unique situation when working with forms, i can as well just dispose of them when not needed?

Comment: When you end the life of your `Ping`-object by closing the form, it is insignificant! **BUT** this is a bad style, and if ever someone else reads code of yours, this can be confusing. So you should preferably dispose of these objects when you don't need them anymore.